# Ubuntu Laptop Booting into GRUB command prompt (shimx64.efi and grubx64.efi not working?)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

**Context:**

Hi everyone, this problem started this morning and has never happened before (to my memory) so I don't think it's something I did to cause this. Basically, I am dual-booting Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 on this machine (Dell Inspiron 5000 Series -- 5570 I think) and when I start the computer it goes to the GRUB 2.04 command prompt (not the rescue prompt to be perfectly clear). I looked at several pages online about this and none of them seem to be specific to my scenario.

**What I've tried:**

I have ls'd into all the partitions and there is no boot or grub directory like the other solutions said, but there is a path (hd0,gpt1)/efi/ubuntu/ which leads to a bunch of files called grubx64.efi, shimx64.efi, mmx64.efi, bootx64.csv, and finally the grub.cfg file. I followed [this](https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/detecting-efi-files-and-booting-them-from-grub/38083) tutorial (I hope that linked properly) to try to run shimx64.efi and grubx64.efi (from what I have gathered, GRUB is a boot manager and the .efi files are executable files that start another boot manager which then starts up Ubuntu -- correct me if I'm wrong I'm still a noob).

**Help:**

I don't know what else I'm supposed to do. If there is a way to make it so that shimx64.efi does its job (maybe by changing some envvars or something) that would be great. Otherwise, I'd still like to keep my files. I do have the option of letting Dell SupportAssist run a diagnostic so that at the very least I can maybe use Windows but that takes very long, and I'm not sure if getting Windows to work will help this situation in particular.

TL;DR: Boot sequence halts on GRUB command line, and I've tried running shimx64.efi and grubx64.efi, both of which bring me back to the GRUB command line.

Comment: If you type exit at grub prompt does it boot? Or `configfile (hd0,5)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`  Where the hd0,5 is changed to the drive, partition where your full install is. If not post link to Summary Report from Boot-Repair.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Typing exit at prompt takes me to what I think is the Windows boot manager. As for the second thing you said. As I mentioned in the question,  I can't find my full install (boot directory?) in any of the partitions. The config file is in (hd0,gpt1) which is set as root.

Edit: It seems I can't install boot-repair without either a CD or USB drive or getting Ubuntu to boot first. I may not be able to link the summary report.

Comment: You should always have a current version flash drive for repair for every system you have installed. Or both a Windows repair flash drive and the Ubuntu live installer.

Comment: @oldfred Somehow my OS was able to boot and install boot repair. It now acts more on-and-off. Weirdly, it shuts down on its own when I close my laptop (not poweroff).
Here is the pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bhJXbX8N5W/

Comment: Both Windows & one Ubuntu entry boot from ESP on sdb1. Second Ubuntu entry boots from ESP on sda1. Both Ubuntu entries boot from hd1,7. But if booting from sdb, it may want to see hd0,7 as boot drive is always hd0. Do depending on which ubuntu entry you use one may automatically work & other may need minor edit as booting (e on grub menu) to change from hd1 to hd0. When I plug in flash drives I often have to do that type of edit. I prefer to have ESP on every drive and have it boot install on that drive.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1515749/ubuntu-icons-disappear-and-everything-freezes. I've linked this page here because I was having the same problem. It seems the root of the issue is a corrupted hard drive. My installation seems to be making it to the stage where I can get into Ubuntu but it freezes after like 30 mins as the post I linked describes.